# Error 12 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsGame1.Player.BaseStrength

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I don't understand why it wont let me do the following. Does anyone know a way I can accomplish this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class Player
    {
        int BaseStrength = 10;
        int BaseIntelligence = 10;
        int BaseDexterity = 10;
        int BaseStamina = 10;
        int BaseSpeed = 10;

        int Damage;
        int SpellDamage;
        int Accuracy;
        int LifePoints;
        int CastingSpeed;

        ***int Damage = (BaseStrength / 2);***

    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Error 12 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsGame1.Player.BaseStrength

Answer (score 2):

If you want Damage to be a value that is calculated based on other fields you should use a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

```
int Damage
{
    get
    {
        return BaseStrength / 2;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to use an ordinary field and set it once when the object is instantiated you should put the initialization code in the constructor.

```
public class Player
{
    int baseStrength = 10;
    int damage;

    public Player()
    {
        damage = baseStrength / 2;
    }
}
```